# Nginx as web file server - new hosted files are unavailable

Tags: docker, nginx

I’ve been working on making (python) scripts which download audio from youtube videos and put audio files on a nginx web file server to be downloaded later (podcast style).

The process works for existing files (people are able to download the files from the nginx webserver), but any new files which are created are unavailable on the webserver even though the files are on the server ok.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Everything is hosted on a Raspberry Pi, the nginx is in a docker container (image: linuxserver/nginx )

Comment: share your nginx conf

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx config add `root` and `autoindex` params. All in section server. Example

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  you-server-name.net; # Change to your domain name 

    root /path/to/your/static/files; # Change to your static file directory

    autoindex on; # Enable directory listing

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Official docs [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)